# bsxfun type function in c#

Tags: c#, matlab, ilnumerics

I m trying to do the equivalent of the following matlab function:

```
outmatrix = bsxfun(@minus,inmatrix, invector);
```

in c sharp. I used this:

```
public static ILArray<double> bsxfun(ILArray<double> inmatrix, ILArray<double> invector)
    {

        for(int i=0; i < inmatrix.getlength(1) ;i++)
        {
            inmatrix[":",i] = inmatrix[":",i] -invector;
        }
        return inmatrix;

    }
```

Utilizing ILNumerics package.

My questions: is this the most efficient way? because my matrices can be large. 
How can I generalize this so that I can specify whether to do minus, plus, times, divide, etc like with a funciton handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ILnumerics you dont need to do anything. ILNumerics automatically operates the vector on the matrix elements correctly:

```
 outmatrix = inmatrix - invector;
```

Docu: http://ilnumerics.net/Opoverload.html

BTW: if you want efficient implementation you must use the ILNumerics Function rules: http://ilnumerics.net/FunctionRules.html

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is not the easiest to maintain.  Do a single check for the operator and repeat the for loop for each different operator.

Comment: thanks. so you would recommend a simple double for loop?